# C system() function vulnerability

Tags: c, security

Suppose we have the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *user = getenv("USER");
        char buffer[4096];

        if (user) {
                snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "/bin/echo %s", user);   
                system(buffer);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Is it possible for a user to cause this program to execute arbitrary commands?

Comment: Do you have actual code that compiles and demonstrates the vulnerability?

Comment: Vulnerability? Where? If that's your real buffer string, then it's going to cause a syntax error in the shell.

Comment: I do have a method in mind, which I'm pretty sure would work, but I'm not sure I want to tell you without knowing more.  Why do you want to exploit this/a vulnerability?

Answer (score 14):

If this is actually in live code somewhere, then whomever wrote it should be forced to write *I will never call `system` on tainted user input again* 1 googol times with a dull pencil.  **Yes.**  As written, this code contains an exploit.  Here's a simple example.

```
tmp$ cat foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {
    char *user = getenv("USER");
    char buffer[4096];
    if (user) {
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "/bin/echo %s", user);
        printf("running %s\n", buffer);
        system(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
tmp$ gcc foo.c
tmp$ mkdir /tmp/xxx
tmp$ ls -ld /tmp/xxx
drwxr-xr-x  2 daveshawley  users  68 Nov 30 22:25 /tmp/xxx/
tmp$ USER='foo; rm -fr /tmp/xxx' ./a.out
running /bin/echo foo; rm -fr /tmp/xxx
foo
tmp$ ls -ld /tmp/xxx
ls: /tmp/xxx: No such file or directory
tmp$
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print out the value of the `USER` environment variable, you can do:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s", getenv("USER"));
```

There's no need to call `system();`.

Comment: I can't modify the code... It's a wargame...

Comment: What kind of wargame? There aren't many games for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Others have told you how to exploit this.  In the spirit of advocating the *right* way to do things, here is a good way to execute `echo` with user input and not have vulnerabilities (barring of course some bug in echo :-)):

```
execlp("echo", string_from_user, NULL);
```

If you deal directly with the `exec` family of syscalls, you can pass unadulterated strings directly to the program without any chance that the shell will misinterpret them, because *there is no shell* in that case.  Hence there is no need to escape.

There are more potential security problems with code like this.  Here are some that I can think of:

- If an untrusted user can modify `/bin/echo`, obviously that untrusted user can make this run arbitrary code.
- If an untrusted user can modify the `PATH` environment variable, my `execlp` example above is vulnerable.  One workaround is to not use the -`p` variants of the `exec` family of syscalls, because those will not check `PATH`.

Answer (score -4):

It is not possible.  You'd have to write something that changes the USER environment parameter that effectively backspaces over the previous characters, and system("string") does not actually use a shell through a pseudo-terminal to execute, which is where backspace processing happens.

*edit*:
Despite comments below, and a down-vote, they are incorrect.

/bin/sh processing (or whatever shell is specified) only processes backspace & other edit characters when attached to a terminal device for input.

In addition, the original author is intent on subverting a program not of his own making.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The string passed to `system()` is interpreted by the shell, and the shell responds to many different special characters - backspace is not necessary.

Comment: According to Open Group [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) definitely calls the shell.

Comment: I disagree.  Shell backspace processing occurs only with pseudo-terminals, which is not what system("") does.

Comment: The vulnerability is not in some program using backspace characters, the vulnerability is in other shell characters.  For example semicolons, backticks, ampersands, `$(rm -rf /)`, etc.

Comment: @AndyFinkenstadt - shell backspace processing may be limited to pseudo-terminals.  The Open Group standard specifies that `system(x)` is equivalent to `execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", x, (char *)0)`.  If the `USER` environment variable contains something like `"foo; rm -fr /"` then it would cause problems when the program is run as a privileged user.  Also note that there is nothing special about the `USER` environment variable that forbids you from changing it.